# What do you call this generalized floor function?

Tags: functions, maxima-minima, ceiling-and-floor-functions, rounding-unit

Given

1. an $n$-tuple of ordinal values $\mathbf{x}$, the members of which are each comparable to one another and
2. a single value $y$, $\mathrm{min}(\mathbf{x})\le y$, which is comparable to any of the members of $\mathbf{x}$,

maximize $x\in \mathbf{x}$, $x\le y$.

(This seems to be a simple, special case among "[constrained extrema](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591347/constrained-extrema-absolute)" problems.)

In terms of the range, this function is like the floor function, except that the range is constrained to $\mathbf{x}$ rather than to the integers.

For example, suppose $\mathbf{x}=(-100, -10, 0, 10, 100)$ and $y=-11$. Then $x=-100$. And if $y=-10$, $x=-10$.

Provided that the constraints are met, I believe this can be expressed in [R](https://www.r-project.org/) as `max(x[x <= y])`.

One application is to the selection of aesthetic boundaries for a plot.

Comment: This is a common thing to do but I don't know if it has a name. I just say "the largest element of **x** less than $y$."

Comment: @JairTaylor I suppose `maxle` (or `maxlt`, as you have it) would be an OK name for a function in a computer program or software library, then. I am still wondering whether the mathematics community has a special name already, though. The $\mathrm{max}$ and $\mathrm{min}$ functions are easy enough to find.